# Import-Module not working from inside docker container (Linux)

Tags: powershell, docker, powershell-core

From inside my docker file, I'm running a powershell script named ci.ps1 which tries to load a module but fails.

Let's suppose in my source directory I have this module :

`src/packages/tools/Powershell/MyModule/MyModule.psm1`

In my ci.ps1 I define PSModulePath :

```
$env:PSModulePath = ($env:PSModulePath + ";" + (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot Powershell) + ";" + ((Get-Item "packages/tools/Powershell")[-1].FullName))
```

The current value of env:PSModulePath is :

```
/root/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/opt/microsoft/powershell/6/Modules;/src/Powershell;/src/packages/tools/Powershell
```

Then I try to import the module

```
Import-Module MyModule
```

but it fails :

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'MyModule' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

Any solutions to fix this issue ? It works outside of a docker container though

Comment: What does your module layout look like?  You need to have the right module structure to import it by name like that.

Comment: It's just a .psm1 file which also imports other modules and exports helper functions

Comment: I'd suggest reading [the documentation on modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/writing-a-windows-powershell-module).

Comment: [This is the relevant section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module#use-the-correct-module-directory-name) on getting module auto-loading to work.

Comment: I'm running powershell on Linux

Comment: My comment is still relevant.  You need to make a proper module if you want to use `PSModulePath`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point, I read the doc you provided, the location of my module is included in the PSModulePath and also it is well-formed  /MyModule/MyModule.psm1

Comment: You also need a module manifest for the loading to work.  You can use the `New-ModuleManifest` cmdlet for a scaffold.